# Is it ok to share my Google Cloud account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a Google Cloud account, in order to investigate its capabilities.

In order to get a trial account, i had to give my personal credit card data.
Now, another person asks me to access my Google Cloud account in order to perform investigations as well.

Is there a potential danger by sharing an account where i gave my credit card information? I am not sure if card details are fully visible to the other person.

Comment: There are three services to understand: a) Google Cloud Platform; b) Google Cloud Billing Account; c) Google Payments account. You can control access for each service. Remember, you are responsible for charges incurred in the project. I recommend that the other person open their own account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other person will see your credit card information so depends on how much you trust that person.

If this is work related, they should be providing credit card details instead of expecting you to use your personal card.

However, try removing those details.

Comment: If i am the owner of the project, and set up another user with the 'Editor' role, will they see my credit card in the dashboard?

Comment: If they have their own login, no

Comment: I added them as an 'Editor' and they received an email with a link to the dashboard. When they enter, they are shown the Dashboard.